# Azure Data lake throwing error - Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am testing azure data lake functions using my storage keys. When I try to create a directory within container, it is throwing me below exception. How do I resolve the error?

Python Code:

```
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

global service_client

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
    "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="demo")
file_system_client.create_directory("demo-directory")
```

Exception:

```
(AuthenticationFailed) Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:f3880178-801f-0073-2c58-09be43000000
Time:2021-02-22T20:22:15.9974202Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. But you passed wrong value to `credential`. You should pass `Key` not `connection string`.

When I passed `connection string` to `credential`, I got the same error message with yours.

[image]

You could find `Key` here:

[image]